# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 - setValue Date Issue

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Can't seem to get my Date type field to accept my new date value. It doesn't throw any errors; it just appears to ignore the setValue function. If I set the date in the UI, a script log will show the following format:

```
{"details": datetypeField = Thu Oct 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(["N/record", "N/format"], function(r, f) {
    var customer = r.load({
        type: r.Type.CUSTOMER, 
        id: "111",
        isDynamic: false,
    }); 

    var today = new Date();  

    customer.setValue({
        fieldId: "custentity_datetypefield",
        value: today
    }); 

    customer.save({
        enableSourcing: true,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that module is a User Event script, but its code isn't connected to any event trigger; I would expect to see a `beforeSubmit` or `afterSubmit` handler wired up in the output of the module. I would also expect that this file would fail to upload when trying to create the Script record.

How are your Script and Deployment records set up? How are you expecting to trigger this code?

You *are* setting the field correctly; Date fields expect a `Date` Object in the `value` property, so that much is definitely correct.